# Delete Folder When User Has File Open

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, check-in

We migrated a folder to the a new Document Library and when trying to delete the original, I get this message. Is there anyway to override this and delete as an administrator? Do I need to force a check-in or is it because someone has a single document open. I tracked down the user in question and he says he closed everything. We even locked down permissions and set everybody to 'Read' but I still cannot delete the Folder

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to solve your problem,

1. Go to library settings
2. In permission and management > click on *Manage files which have no checked in version*
3. When you see list of checked out files
4. Take ownership of selection > select the document for which you want to take ownership
5. Delete it or update it, it's up to you

I didn't do this by my self > not unit tested.

For more details, you can go through this below mention links.

1. [SharePoint - Unable to delete a locked or checked out document](https://answers.uillinois.edu/systemoffices/page.php?id=66454)
2. [Resolving "File Checked Out Or Locked For Editing" Issue In SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/resolving-file-checked-out-or-locked-for-editing-issue-in-sharepoint/)